# Why is there a difference between MATLAB and manual calculation for eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matlab

We have a matrix $A$ as below

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&2\\0&1&2\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}.$$

I know the eigenvalues are 1 and 2 because matrix $A$ is a triangular matrix.

And by working it manually, my eigenvector for eigenvalue of $1$ is $(1,0,0)^T$, and eigenvector for eigenvalue of 2 is $(6,2,1)^T$.

However, when I used MATLAB to find my eigenvectors using `>>[P D] = eig(A)`, I get `{(1,0,0), (-1,0,0)}` for eigenvalue of `1`, and even more weird `{(640/683, 640/2049, 320/2049)}` eigenvector for eigenvalue of `2`.

I know they're the same, since the eigenvectors in MATLAB are scalars of the eigenvectors above. However, my question is, why is there a difference between the MATLAB's eigenvectors and my own eigenvectors?

Comment: Matlab is trying to diagonalize a matrix that cannot be diagonalized. Rather than "recognizing" that the matrix is not diagonalizable, it gives a non-sensical answer due to numerical error

Comment: @BenGrossmann I think I am starting to understand what you mean.. do you mind elaborating a little?
edit: so is MATLAB wrong in this case?

Comment: It is "wrong" in the sense that $(1,0,0)$ an $(-1,0,0)$ are eigenvector. Other than that, it gives the correct answer. Since the eigenvector for $2$ is a multiple of the vector you gave, your answer and Matlab's are consistent.

Comment: @BenGrossmann thanks alot, appreciate it.